# Kivy - Why does the source image distort in this way when set as Button background_normal image?

Tags: python, image, button, kivy

I am having an issue when placing an icon.png as the background_normal of a button within Kivy. When the image is displayed within the button there are black areas that stretch from the sides of the icon.  Some icons appear as the they are stretched forwards from the middle as well.  All icons used have a transparent background colour.

I have ensured the source image is the same res (80x80px) as the button it is placed within. Also tried setting allow_stretch to False and kee_ration to True.  None seem to fix the issue.

This is how the icon should display
[image: normal]

This is how it is being displayed within the button(ignore the brown canvas colour)

[image: screenshot]

Below is the .kv section which creates the Button within a BoxLayout and then applies the source  image as the background

```
<SettingsScreen>
name: "Settings"
size: self.width, self.height

BoxLayout:
    size: root.width, root.height
    cols:1
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: hex('#D29F7C')
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (1920, 80)
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Button:
            background_colour: 0, 0, 0, 0
            background_normal: r'C:\Users\James\Documents\Coding\Python\Practice Projects\Gardening App\Icons\Home.png'
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (80, 80)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#AB9D92')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            bold: True
            color: 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1
            font_hinting: 'normal'
            font_size: 40
            font_name: 'calibril.ttf'
            text: 'Menu'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Menu"
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Apologies, the code i had originally used has now been scrapped.  However, what i noticed was that when i reduced the source image size below the widget (Button) size, the distortion no longer occurred.  i.e  Icon (80x80px) + Button (80x80px) = Distorted.    Icon (64x64px) + Button (80x80px) = No distortion.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to arise when the image being applied to the background of the button is the same resolution as the button itself.  When the image size was decreased to slightly below that of the button the distortion disappeared.